# path diagram with concurrent variables - regression or correlation?

Tags: path-model

I have several variables in my model and there were a few created in the same time point which I make plan not to predict who is ``predicting'' who, but just to understand their relationship. Basically I am more interested in their correlations instead of regression per se. Is it possible to do that? Say my lavaan path is currently like this:

```
math3 ~ read3+ math2 + read2 + math1 + read1
read3 ~ math2 + read2 + math1 + read1
math2 ~ read1 + read2 + math1
read2 ~ math1 + read1
math1 ~ read1
```

However, I am more interested in how read3 and math3, read2 and math2, math1 and read1 correlate.... not 'regression'

Or is it actually the same as regression coefficient is the same as correlation coefficient? for instance, with math1 ~ read1, can I interpret as a correlation?

(My model included other paths, so this may looked like a saturated model but it is not...)

Comment: When performing a regression analysis, you are essentially studying correlations. In fact, when everything is Gaussian, you can write out all the coefficients in terms of partial correlations (essentially correlation with conditioning).  In terms of understanding the relationships between your variables, this type of path analysis seems quite appropriate.

Comment: @JohnAustin I think the logic works, but I am using the note : http://core.ecu.edu/psyc/wuenschk/MV/SEM/Path.pdf and p.2 says ". Were we to decide that not only does high SES cause high nAch but that
also high nAch causes high SES, we could not use path analysis." So it seem we cannot use path analysis for correlations...

Comment: To clarify: You can use regression in this way to study the correlations, but not causality (i.e. directions). The system of regression equations you wrote down makes perfect sense - as long as you interpret the equations correctly. If you wanted to study causality using SEM / path analysis it would indeed be much trickier (but doable!).

Comment: @JohnAustin, oh how to do that in path analysis? Currently I am trying read2 ~~ math2 but I don't think this really works. I was just trying to see how it looks now...

Comment: Are you wanting to study correlations or causation? They are very different problems!

Comment: @JohnAustin I want to study the correlations of variables at the same time point (e.g, read1 and math1) but causation at different time point (e.g. read1 -> math2)